# Is calling base implementation mandatory when overriding?

Tags: c#, inheritance, overriding

For some reasons this morning I look at that code (wpf) and get puzzled

```
protected override void OnMouseEnter(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnMouseEnter(e);
}
```

Usually, I'd simply replace that `base` call with my code.

Is `base` call important generally? I don't do it when, to example, overriding `OnRender`, is it bad? If it would be my class, then I'd obviously know for sure when to call and when to not call.

Comment: If it was mandatory, do you not think that you'd get a compiler warning/error if you don't do it?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, how would compiler know if I had implemented it fully and don't need to call `base`? It's *safe* to remove base call from compiler point of view, but is it really *safe* (wpf-wise)?

Comment: Unless you have a good reason not to, you should call the base method when overriding.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, exactly my point! I just start thinking this morning "why am I simply deleting base call?" and honestly, have no idea from where this bad habit comes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mostly it is best to call the base class, however, like said above it depends.

Actually it depends on:

- If the overridden method does something IN ADDITIONAL, then you should call the parent, either before or after your code.
- If the overridden method does something DIFFERENT, then you should not call the parent.

In your case it does probably something in additional, because you don't know what the base method is doing exactly, possibly more than you might imagine and you want to 'add' your own functionality.

Edit: (with remark of Sriram Sakthivel): because of the Liskov substitution principle, it is not a good idea to do something different in an overridden method. My remark: very true, but sometimes you don't even know the code of the base class, or you want to do something different despite this knowledge (you might add as a comment in the code that you do this deliberately).

Comment: I am going to refactor a lot of code today. Thanks.

Comment: If the overridden method does something DIFFERENT then you're doing something wrong, It violates [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). Nevertheless I've done it :) Just said to be aware of..

Answer (score 3):

That depends upon what base class method is doing. For instance in winforms, if you override `OnLoad` method and you forgot to call `base.OnLoad(e)` then `Form.Load` event will never fire as `base.OnLoad(e)` is the method which fires the event.

So short answer would be *it depends*.

Comment: Is it same in my case? Will `MouseEnter` event become broken without `base` call?

Comment: @Sinatr Is this winforms or wpf?

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy answer to whether you need to call the base function.  It just depends on whether you want to replace the base function or supplement it.  If you don't know what the base function does, then calling the base function first before adding your supplemental code is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to give a definitive *generalized* answer here, except for this:

> Unless you have a good reason not to, you should always call the base method when overriding.

Now, how do you know if you have a good reason not to? Well, you will need to know what the base method does, whether you need it, whether it is safe to drop the call, etc.

In other words, a *generalized* answer is impossible, it all comes down to specific cases.